# Login screen all screwed up on wakeup from suspend

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics, gma500, poulsbo

I am new to Linux/Ubuntu. Any input is greatly appreciated.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on an eeepc 1101HA. Using the Intel GMA500 "Poulsbo" video hardware.

The display graphics are fine at all times when I power on the computer fresh, but as soon as I close the lid or suspend from the cog menu and I wake up the computer, it looks like this:

[image: distorted screen]

Every second line of pixels is black, the display seems to be on a angle and repeated 3 times, and the middle section works for clicking and interacting with the mouse. Everything works normally, it just appears to be the graphics. Will this problem be solved if I install an older version of Ubuntu like 11.10?

Any insights into where I should be looking/reading up on how to fix this are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It seems I got this symptom fixed by following instructions from [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsPoulsbo).

Relevant part here:

> Fix suspend
>
> If suspend does not work for you, there are various quirk options you
>   can try. See the manpage for pm-suspend for a list of them all. One
>   that has been reported to help is quirk-vbemode-restore, which saves
>   and restores the current VESA mode.
>
> To test it, open a terminal and use the following commands
>
> sudo pm-suspend --quirk-vbemode-restore
>
> That should suspend your system. If you are able to resume, you'll
>   want to configure UBuntu to use this option every time you suspend. To
>   do this oOpen a terminal and use the following commands:
>
> gksu gedit /etc/pm/config.d/gma500
>
> Add in the following code and save the file:
>
> ADD_PARAMETERS='--quirk-vbemode-restore'